# How can I list all user-created attributes?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I tried to find all user-created attributes with the code below and it returns many other default attributes, like `db/unique` and `fressian/tag`.

I'd like to get a set without them, so I was wondering if there is a better way to get it than filtering out the attributes by their prefixes.

Thanks

```
(q {:find '[?ident]
    :where '[[:db.part/db :db.install/attribute ?p]
             [?p :db/ident ?ident]]} db)
```

or

```
(filter (partial instance? datomic.db.Attribute)
      (:elements (p/db)))
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to white/black list the namespaces you want to filter out or include. Note there's **no difference** between some of Datomic's built-in attributes and user attributes. You can freely create attributes in any of the *system* namespaces e.g. `db.type` but of course you're not supposed to do it.

Having said that, there's only a few namespaces used for system attributes so you could simply filter out those *known* namespaces. e.g.

```
(def system-ns #{"db" "db.type" "db.install" "db.part" 
                 "db.lang" "fressian" "db.unique" "db.excise" 
                 "db.cardinality" "db.fn"})

(d/q '[:find ?e ?ident
   :in $ ?system-ns
   :where
   [?e :db/ident ?ident]
   [(namespace ?ident) ?ns]
   [((comp not contains?) ?system-ns ?ns)]]
 (d/db conn) system-ns)
```

Comment: I think `system-ns` has expanded to include, at least, `"db.alter" "db.bootstrap" "db.sys"`

Comment: Why not just filter out all db.* namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
(defn get-user-schema [db]
  (->> (d/q '[:find ?e
              :where
              [?e :db/ident ?ident]
              [(namespace ?ident) ?ns]
              (not (or [(contains? #{"db" "fressian"} ?ns)]
                       [(.startsWith ?ns "db.")]))]
            db)
       (map #(->> % first (d/entity db) d/touch (into {})))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Show user-defined attributes:**

```clj
(clojure.pprint/print-table (->> (d/pull db '{:eid 0 :selector [{:db.install/attribute [*]}]})
                                 :db.install/attribute
                                 (remove (fn [m] (or (clojure.string/starts-with? (namespace (:db/ident m)) "db") (clojure.string/starts-with? (namespace (:db/ident m)) "fressian"))))
                                 (map #(update % :db/valueType :db/ident))
                                 (map #(update % :db/cardinality :db/ident))
                                 (sort-by :db/ident)))
```

(Adapted from `get-schema` function here: [Datomicion-starter - GitHub](https://github.com/Datomic/ion-starter/blob/master/src/datomic/ion/starter.clj))

**Output:**

```
| :db/id |    :db/ident |    :db/valueType |      :db/cardinality |
|--------+--------------+------------------+----------------------|
|     74 |   :inv/color | :db.type/keyword |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     80 |   :inv/count |    :db.type/long |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     75 |    :inv/size | :db.type/keyword |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     73 |     :inv/sku |  :db.type/string |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     76 |    :inv/type | :db.type/keyword |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     79 |  :item/count |    :db.type/long |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     78 |     :item/id |     :db.type/ref |  :db.cardinality/one |
|     77 | :order/items |     :db.type/ref | :db.cardinality/many |
```