# How can I get the current Datomic schema?

Tags: schema, datomic

Since the Datomic schema is itself stored in Datomic, how can I query Datomic to get the currently installed schema? I want to only get the user-level schema, excluding the system-level schema that has things like partitions.

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281499/how-can-i-list-all-user-created-attributes. I think that's what you want. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only started learning Datomic and Datalog pretty recently, so I don't know if things have just changed in the three years it's been since the previous answer, or if this is just a different way of doing the same thing:

```
[:find ?attr ?type ?card
 :where
 [_ :db.install/attribute ?a]
 [?a :db/valueType ?t]
 [?a :db/cardinality ?c]
 [?a :db/ident ?attr]
 [?t :db/ident ?type]
 [?c :db/ident ?card]]
```

It will give you something that looks like this:

[image: schema query results]

Taken from http://www.learndatalogtoday.org/chapter/4 (solution to challenge 2 at the bottom).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Datomic docs](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html), the user-level schema should be installed to the `:db.part/db` partition. The following function gets all the schema attributes in that partition, given a Datomic connection.

```
(defn get-user-schema [conn]
  (d/q '[:find ?id
         :where [?e :db/ident ?id]
                [_ :db.install/attribute ?e]
                [?e :db.install/partition :db.part/db]]
       (d/db conn)))
```

Related: [is there a canonical way to grab all idents from a particular datomic partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720909/is-there-a-canonical-way-to-grab-all-idents-from-a-particular-datomic-partition)

Comment: this part of the where clause doesn't seem to work ```[?e :db.install/partition :db.part/db]``` , so the answer is only partially correct, a2ndrade's answer in the comment on the initial question works like a charm.

Comment: This solution gave me `[]` on my db. When I used the answer from @weltschmerz (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726168/361855) I got my schema.

Comment: Author here. Yeah I think the partition stuff has changed since my answer, at least in Datomic Cloud. Marking the other answer as correct now.